# Global functions in TypeScript for jest testing

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app-typescript and want to create a function that will be available in every test file similar to [jest's globals](http://jestjs.io/docs/en/api).

Is it possible to write a function in the `src/setupTest.ts` file that will be available in every test file?

I want to write a `react-intl` helper that I can use when testing components. I have the following code:

```
// src/setupTests.ts
import { createIntlWrapper } from 'test-utils/react/react-intl';
import enMessages from './assets/locales/en.json';

const wrapIntl = createIntlWrapper('en', enMessages);
```

The `createIntlWrapper` returns a function which mimic [this helper function](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#helper-function-2).

When I need to test components that have react-intl components, I want to be able to wrap the JSX with `wrapIntl(<SampleComponent />)` without importing the code above in every file.

Comment: Did you find a solution to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
global.wrapIntl = createIntlWrapper('en', enMessages);
```

it's the node's equivalent to `window.someGlobalVariable = 'something'`

Comment: I tried that and received the following error `Property 'wrapIntl' does not exist on type 'Global'.` I tried adding `// @ts-ignore` temporarily but it was still undefined in other test files.

Comment: Ah, I see, then before that line try `declare let global:any;`. Or drop the  `global.` part and add `declare let wrapIntl: any;`. `declare` is the way to create global variables in typescript.

Comment: great! should be accepted answer @ssylviageo!